# What is a Zirconium Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee).</sub>

<sub>I copied the array code - hope you guys don't mind. =)</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Zirconium Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Zirconium Words™ | Not Zirconium Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| SATURN | MERCURY |
| NAYSAYER | HORSE |
| TOE | FOOT |
| ASTEROID | METEORITE |
| INQUIRE | QUESTION |
| SEPTILLION | THREE |
| LEVER | BEAVER |
| UPCAST | DOWNCAST |
| GLUE | TAPE |
| SILLY | HAHAHAHAHA |

The CSV version <sub>(I wonder what that means)</sub>, if you want to look at it.

```
Zirconium Words™,Not Zirconium Words™
SATURN,MERCURY
NAYSAYER,HORSE
TOE,FOOT
ASTEROID,METEORITE
INQUIRE,QUESTION
SEPTILLION,THREE
LEVER,BEAVER
UPCAST,DOWNCAST
GLUE,TAPE
SILLY,HAHAHAHAHA
```

Comment: For the record, [here's what CSV means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

Comment: Also for the record, the What is a ... Word™️ template specifically exists so people don’t have to reinvent the wheel every time. You’re free to use it with my blessing :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that a Zirconium Word is such that

> If we add the alphabetic score (A=1, B=2, ..., Z=26) of the first three letters of the word, the answer is 40 (i.e, the atomic number of Zirconium).

One exception

> There seems to be one exception to this pattern which is the word LEVER which has a score of 39 but I'm inclined to think this is an error as the pattern fits so well on all the other words and the value is so close.